# scraping linkedin profile without selenium and API

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, scrape

I want scraping profile LinkedIn by URL

like ; https://www.linkedin.com/in/andrew-marson-90a74015/

i want get some data from it

I was use selenum before but I want make it more fast

so I want use request.get(url, auth=**** )
but to get data u need to login so can I get the page by **auth = ('user', 'pass')**

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
test = requests.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/andrew-marson-90a74015/', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
print(test.text)
```

Comment: _...without selenium and API..._ why to tag `selenium`?

Comment: maybe someone know the why

Comment: That can be `True` if you add any other tag, even the language bindings _java_, _Python_, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

email = ""
password = ""

client = requests.Session()

HOMEPAGE_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com'
LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login'

html = client.get(HOMEPAGE_URL).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
csrf = soup.find('input', {'name': 'loginCsrfParam'}).get('value')

login_information = {
    'session_key': email,
    'session_password': password,
    'loginCsrfParam': csrf,
    'trk': 'guest_homepage-basic_sign-in-submit'
}

client.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_information)

response = client.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/andrew-marson-90a74015/')
print(response.text)
```

this code not work

Answer (score 1):

use beautifulsoup or scrapy, both works fine for scraping for task which don't require selenium.

```
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with Session() as s:
    site = s.get("https://www.linkedin.com/")
    bs_content = bs(site.content, "html.parser")
    token = bs_content.find("input", {"name": "loginCsrfParam"})["value"]
    login_data = {"username": "admin",
                  "password": "12345", "loginCsrfParam": token}
    s.post("https://www.linkedin.com/login", login_data)
    home_page = s.get("https://www.linkedin.com/")
    print(home_page.content)
```

Comment: linkedin no have javascipte and change dom ... the problem how to login by request.get(url)

Comment: I modified the answer have a look into it, i can't try it since I don't have an account in linkedin. So I can't test it properly